# WPF, MVVM, and effective navigation / control flow

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I am currently building an application based on a real world scenario, to help me learn and understand WPF and MVVM. To that end I have read and worked through Karl Shifflett's ["In The Box"](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2010/11/07/in-the-box-ndash-mvvm-training/) VSIX, and I was able to adapt most of the concepts to the application that I am working on.

While I think MVVM is a powerful design pattern, it does (seemingly) make things that were once trivial (e.g. displaying messages, navigation, interacting with multiple window), not so trivial or straightforward. Now onto the crux of my problem / confusion.

The WPF application that I am working on is a Windows based application, and I am working from a set of basic requirements:

- A basic login screen
- After a successful login, close the login screen and open the actual application
- Simulate a typical program workflow (opening "child" windows via button clicks, displaying modal windows, etc.)
- Preform data validation / error handling
- Log out

I am used to working with MDI Applications on a windows platform where interactions on a parent form cause child forms to open; I understand that MDI is not something that WPF supports and I am fine with approaching development from a different perspective. My UI would still work in a similar manner to a MDI application though: I have my application layout, and as I interact with that layout my application will respond by opening windows, displaying messages, and so on. It isn't clear to me (via MVVM) how to interact with multiple windows, or how well MVVM would scale to a large application with many windows / views.

I am not opposed to using something like Prism, but I haven't found a good article on how Prism approaches my particular problem very well.  Any help, advice, feedback, or otherwise is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Brian Lagunas has a video series on his website called "Building IG Outlook where he builds out a basic Outlook clone using Prism. It will cover all the scenarios where Prism will help you.  http://brianlagunas.com/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at `nRoute` Framework?

A link can be found [here](http://nroute.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

There are actually some good tuturials about prism

[Link 1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/507077/PRISM-application-from-the-beginning-part-I)

[Link 2 (Part II of Link1)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/507608/PRISM-application-from-the-beginning-Part-II)

[Link 3](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/628914/Prism-WPF-standalone-and-interaction-modules-in-VS)

For a more straight forrward application (not very complex and modular), you can always create a aplication, with a main window that manages child usercontrols (login window, menu window, other windows ...)

For example, create a window a contentpresenter in it, and in codebehind:

```
public partial class ShellWindow: Window
{
    public enum PagesTypes { Login, Home }

    PagesTypes currentOpenedPage;

    LoginUserControl login;
    HomeUserControl home;

    public WindowController()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        login = new LoginUserControl ();
        login.GoToPage += new LoginUserControl.ChangePageHandler(GoToPage);
        GoToPage(PagesTypes.Login);
    }

    public void GoToPage(PagesTypes page)
    {
        switch (page)
        {
            case PagesTypes.Login:
            //Close last opened usercontrol, 
            ....
            //open new usercontrol
            login = new LoginUserControl();
            contentpresenter.content = login;
            break;

            //other pages cases
            ....
        }
        currentOpenedPage = page;

    }

}
```

And in for example the login usercontrol:

```
public partial class LoginUserControl : UserControl
{
    internal delegate void ChangePageHandler(ShellWindow.PagesTypes toPage);
    internal event ChangePageHandler GoToPage;

    public LoginUserControl()
    {...}

    //Methods for login 
    .....

    internal void LoginOK()
    {
        if(this.GoToPage != null)
            GoToPage(ShellWindow.PagesTypes.Home);
    }
}
```

You can build a good dynamic using this method changing usercontrols, simulating diferent windows.

Hope this gives you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

MVVMing your child windows actually can be kind of easy, especially if you decide that a tabbed interface is OK.  Your outer window's view model simply has a collection of ChildWindowViewModel.  You create a new tab just by creating the new view model, asking the outer window to add it to it's collection, and WPF's DataTemplate awesomeness will take care of the proper display.  You'll have to do some fiddling to get tab 'close' operations working the way you want.  It's kind of a pain but doable.

If you really want to do MDI, there's nothing built into WPF for it (I think Microsoft has decided that it is a bad UI pattern now?), but there may be 3rd party controls out there for it.  Any good one will still mirror this solution where their MDI container control will bind to your list of child window view models.